# Anything like window.load that can be used after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window

I came across this complication when loading content through ajax. I usually use window.load to check if everything is loaded up and only than I display content, there is loading animation before.

this is done to hide bits from user that are styled via javascript and without hiding them page looks ugly for a split second. It stopped working after I started loading content via ajax, and it than turned out that you can't use window.load with it.

I tried looking for replacement method, but had no luck. Has anyone had luck with this and found similar solution that works with ajax?

Comment: ajaxObj.onreadystatechange = function() { if (ajaxObj.readyState = 4) {} };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `success:` callback on your `$.ajax()` call to do the styling and display your page once the content is loaded.

Comment: or `complete:` if you don't care whether the request succeeded or failed.

Comment: Although, I'd recommend you use the `$.ajax().done()` syntax over the `$.ajax({ success: fn })` one, primarily for the reason that the former is more akin to DOM2 event subscription, and it allows multiple handlers to be attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: "test.html",
context: document.body
}).done(function() {
//your code for loading done goes here
});
```

Should work as expected :)